Does the IAM policy need include access to the CMK chosen for DynamoDB encryption in order to access the DynamoDB?
When I create a DynamoDB table, I can choose to encrypt the table use a customer managed Key (CMK). My question is when creating an IAM role/policy to allow say, read/write to the table, like dynamodb:GetItem, do I also need to add permission to access the key itself?
I did not seem see this in the AWS DynamoDB doc.

Yes you do, you can either add the permissions to the role, or to the key policy.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/encryption.usagenotes.html#dynamodb-kms-authz
